# Superscript and subscript in one axis label

Tags: r, ggplot2, axis-labels, subscript, superscript

I'm trying to code for a label that says "13CO2%" in ggplot. My sample code as guessed from other posts here is

> `xlab("Treatment") + ylab(expression(paste("^13, CO[2], %"))) +`

This results in verbatim pasting including the arrows and brackets. Can anyone spot the issue, I'm sure it's nothing major but I think I'm following the basic rules of superscript=^ and subscript = [].

> `xlab("Treatment") +
> ylab(expression(paste("^13, CO[2], %"))) +'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No need to use `paste`. You could go on with `expression`. However, note the use of `*` to glue the parts of your expression which are needed to make it a valid expression. Also, you have to quote the % symbol and use  an invisible `phantom()` to which you could add your superscript.

```r
library(ggplot2)

ggplot(mtcars, aes(hp, mpg)) +
  geom_point() +
  ylab(expression(phantom()^{13}*CO[2]*"%"))
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you! The magic stars fixed it for me! Have a great day!